# WPF - exe is crashing on close

Tags: wpf, deployment, windows-7, .net-4.0, crash-reports

Our WPF application is crashing on closing it (using cross button) with below error details. Is this related to any unmanaged code not being handled properly?

We are using .Net 4.0 framework and Windows 7 machine to install and run it.

The business class of the solution is having one web service reference to external .asmx path. Not sure if this can be an issue. I also checked the custom log trace file and application event log, but nothing is found there.

Problem signature:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MoneyDesk.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.12.16
  Application Timestamp: 57023aab
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.19135
  Fault Module Timestamp:   56a1c9ac
  Exception Code:   c0020001
  Exception Offset: 000000000000965d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 97cc
  Additional Information 2: 97cc899a944cd5ead2ae7642164506a1
  Additional Information 3: 2288
  Additional Information 4: 22884be20c5137a5026bc4f0e8b43aa2
```

Comment: has to be disposing of some resources

Comment: But this error does not come when I run the application in debug mode by pressing F5. It comes only when I run the exe from release folder